# Can't debug UART communication properly from GPS to STM32

Tags: stm32, uart

I'm trying to debug my NEO7M GPS-tracker with STM32H7. NEO chip has UART interface so I set up UART and start coding (Keil v5). It's clear but not for me.

What's going on here:

NEO7M is transmitting data periodically so it looks like DATA----IDLE----DATA----IDLE. All I need is to receive the whole information and send it to some parsing functions.

In main.c I have this:

```
ReadGPS(RecievedData);
ReadTime(RecievedData, Time);
```

And these functions look like this:

```
void ReadGPS(char *RecievedData){
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)RecievedData, GPS_DATA_SIZE);
}

void ReadTime(char *RecievedData, uint8_t *Time){
    ***parsing algorithm***
}
```

So I'm pulling RecievedData pointer to ReadGPS function, reading payload and then using RecievedData in parsing function. Great!

My problem:

If I start a debug session without any breakpoints, in Watch Window data in RecievedData variable changes and parsers work great. BUT when I start using breakpoints, only first symbol of RecievedData is changing, and another 400 symbols are the same as before, and parsers give me wrong information. I tried to use UART receiving function without interrupt, but got the same.

UPD:

This is how it looks like when code running without breakpoints. I see whole UART data packet updating every second.

[image]

When I use step by step mode only the first symbol of recieved data is updating.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be if you debug, the GPS doesn't stop sending data and the buffers fill up. This means you need to have some kind of code to clear the receive buffer or handle the case of receiving two or more packets or half a packet. The way to know is check the receive buffer while debugging and compare the received packet with a normal packet.

Comment: Thank you but I cant understand why only the first character is changing. GPS doesn't stop sending data, it's true. I can start  recieving in the middle of data while debugging, but in this case I would get new buffer starting in the middle of data, not just first character.

Comment: Update your question with the all of the buffer information.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that (A) the GPS just continually spews data packets, and (B) you have code that successfully *receives* the packets, and (C) you are trying to debug higher-level code that does something with the packets that have been received?

If all those things are true, then I would write a program to capture a whole sequence of packets to a file, and then I would debug and/or test the higher-level code *on my development PC* while it reads the saved packets from a file.

Comment: Now way. I'm working on system that must process the data in real-time by itself.

Comment: @dimanchique, I don't understand. Does "now way" mean that at least one of my (A), (B), or (C) above is not true? Or does it mean something else? When I'm developing a real-time, embedded application, I strive to ensure that most of the code can be tested and debugged independently of "time" and, independently of the target platform. What can't be tested in a time-independent way often can be tested with "simulated" real-time.

Comment: FYI: The kind of thing I'm talking about... I'll sometimes have two projects that build from the same source code; One project builds the image for the embedded system, and the other project builds a PC application in which I can test and debug _most_ of the code. If the application needs to talk to external devices (e.g., your GPS unit,) then I'll build simulators into the PC app that mimic the device in repeatable (often, scriptable) ways. If the application depends on real-time, then the PC version will get "timestamps" from a simulated source that the tests can control, etc.

Comment: @dimanchique the phrase is `no way`

Comment: @SolomonSlow sorry, I didn't understand you :) A, B and C is true but problem is how to recieve data correctly not how to work with this data. That's what I mean

Comment: @dimanchique, (B) can't be "true" if the "problem is how to receive data." I thought your problem was that the UART stopped working when you were trying to debug _other_ code. I was trying to suggest that you debug the other code using canned data instead of depending on the UART. But, if you are trying to debug the UART code itself, then my advice will not be of any help. Let me know, and I will delete my answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thank you! As I said before everything works fine when code running without any breakpoints. I see variables refreshing in Watch Window. When I use step by step debugging in Watch Window only first symbol of UART data is refreshing. I guess my code is correct and it's just a debuging problem

Comment: @dimanchique, In that case, my answer stands. If the code that you are trying to debug is not the UART code, then debug it in a different environment where there is no UART. Use "canned" data from a file or an initialized array. Then when you get the bugs out, copy it back into your embedded app.